# How to delete text or blank lines with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete 'third' and blanks lines from my.txt below and then store the o/p in my.txt
what should be the sed command? 
Note: this should be in a loop till end of the file

```
my.txt -

first

sec


third


third

third
```

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU sed, the overwrite is trivial with the '`-i`' option; using standard sed, you have to write to a temporary file and then copy that over the original.

The other answers pre-date the 'blank lines' requirement in the question.

```
sed -i '/third/d;/^[ ]*$/d' my.txt
```

The first part of the command, up to the semi-colon, looks for 'third' and deletes any matching line.  The second part of the command looks for any line consisting of zero or more blanks and deletes them.  If you want to delete lines with blanks and tabs, add a tab in the character class -- there isn't a convenient way to show tabs in the SO markup language.

You could equivalently write:

```
sed -i -e '/third/d' -e '/^[ ]*$/d' my.txt
```

And for non-GNU sed, you would use:

```
sed '/third/d;/^[ ]*$/d' my.txt > x.$$
cp x.$$ my.txt
rm -f x.$$
```

Comment: Without GNU sed, an alternate way is to use plain `ed`. While the commands are the same, the overall syntax is different though.

Comment: You can use `\t` in your character class (`[ \t]`) or use `[[:blank:]]` (space or tab) or `[[:space:]]` (in the POSIX locale: space, tab, newline, carriage return, form feed and vertical tab. In the last example, it's better to do `sed ... && cp ...` so the original file isn't lost if the `sed` fails.

Comment: @Dennis: You are probably correct about '`\t`' for GNU sed; however, the POSIX standard does not recognize/mandate it, and neither does Solaris 10 (to name but one platform where GNU sed is not the default).  Superficially, Solaris 10 sed seems to recognize '[[:blank:]]' etc, but it does not seem to act on them.  All the world is not using GNU.  You're right about the conditional copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sed  -i -r '/^(third|)$/d' my.txt
```

Comment: That uses an extended regular expression which standard (POSIX) 'sed' does not support.  It's not wrong - it is just an extension that should be noted.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/third//g' my.txt
```

would modify the file in-place.

Comment: This won't delete the line, it will just replace 'third' with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

[`sed`](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) is a *stream editor*, i.e. it is for editing *streams* (pipes) not files. If you want to edit files, you should use a file editor such as [`ed`](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ed.html):

```
ed my.txt <<-HERE
  ,g/^third$/d
  ,g/^$/d
  w
  q
HERE
```

Comment: What is the significance of the commas preceding the global commands?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: It's the address. `a,b` means "from line `a` to line `b`". The default value for `a` is `1`, the default value for `b` is `$`, i.e. the last line. Ergo, `,` means "from line `1` to the last line", IOW the entire file. Since `ed` is a file editor, it can actually move around in the file, therefore all commands take an address. `sed` OTOH can't expect to be able to do that, because you generally cannot go backwards in a stream.

Comment: OK: I've always simply used `g/^third$/d` because the scope of the global search is the whole file unless you specify otherwise.  If I wanted to limit the operation to the prior line starting with 'x' to the following line beginning with 'z', then `?^x?,/^z/g/^third$/d`, for example.  But it hadn't occurred to me to add the comma - and I probably won't on those odd occasions when I do use 'ed'.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: It never occurred to me that the address is optional for `g`. I just now realized that I leave off the address all the time for `w`, so I can obviously also do it for `g`. I definitely need to work on my standardese-parsing skills ...

Comment: This distinction between *streams* and *files* is, at best, pedantic.